# Deleting a range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a fairly large database (MySQL) with over 20,000 records and I need to delete a select few records. for example I deleted record 3106 and I need to delete 3107,3108,3207,3458,3414. I just don't know how to multi delete.

Example:

```
DELETE FROM `serial_codes` WHERE `serial_codes`.`SerialID` = 3106 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `in` function:

```
DELETE FROM `serial_codes` WHERE `serial_codes`.`SerialID` in (3106, 3107,...)
```

or `OR`

```
DELETE FROM `serial_codes` WHERE `serial_codes`.`SerialID` = 3106 or  `serial_codes`.`SerialID` = 3107 or ...
```

Comment: Why do you write all the tokens in uppercase (like good coding style) but `IN` in lower case? clean code bro!

Comment: @DanFromGermany uppercase tokens are copied from the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried this and it worked a charm. Also thank you all for your speedy responses you've been a real help.

Comment: I did'nt create the database I am just managing it so I would not know why they did not use Upper case @DanFromGermany

Comment: I was just sayin that I'd expect cleaner code, better codestyle and a better answer from someone with almost 40k rep points and silver mysql badge. Of course `in()` is not incorrect, but `IN()` is better practice. The answer does not show much effort, and does not even link to the documentation (mysql.com).

Comment: @DanFromGermany i have never seen a style guide that functions in sql must be uppercase. Also a link to mysql documentation is not necessary in this case

Comment: @Jens Links to the official documentation should be included in the answer, I can't find where this is written down currently. MySQL code style see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/coding-style.html `Write SQL statements in the style of the MySQL Reference Manual [...] SQL keywords and reserved words: uppercase`.

Comment: There is also http://www.sqlstyle.guide/ by Simon Holywell which is very very widely used: `Always use uppercase for the reserved keywords`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (if you know the id's beforehand) is to use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

```
expr IN (value,...)
```

Example:

```
DELETE FROM `serial_codes`
      WHERE `serial_codes`.`SerialID` IN (3016, 3107, 3108, 3207, 3458, 3414)
```

The `LIMIT` clause can be omitted as the resultset to be deleted is limited to the amount of values in the `IN()` function.

If you have sequencial id's to be deleted (eg. 1, 2, 3, ...), a real range, you can also use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

Example:

```
DELETE FROM `serial_codes`
      WHERE `serial_codes`.`SerialID` BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in` of SQL

```
DELETE FROM `serial_codes` WHERE `serial_codes`.`SerialID` in (3107,3108,3207,3458,3414)
```